# How to use android.opengl.GLES10 objects

Tags: android, opengl-es

I am trying to understand and enhance the GLTron port for android, all the code can be found on : https://github.com/flide/android-gltron.git

Now here is the question along with the pretext :

On the Android developer's guide here : 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/opengl.html
It says and I quote - "android.opengl - This package provides a static interface to the OpenGL ES 1.0/1.1 classes and better performance than the javax.microedition.khronos package interfaces."

But if I try to switch the objects in the "onSurfaceCreated(GL10 , EGLConfig)" function to the relevant objects of android.opengl package I get the following error when I try to switch to android.opengl.EGLConfig object rather than using the "javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLConfig" :

> error: OpenGLView is not abstract and does not override abstract method onSurfaceCreated(GL10,EGLConfig) in Renderer

I get a similar error when switch to the GLES10 object from the android.opengl package.

Am I missing something here? How can I use the classes from android.opengl package if GLSurfaceView class won't accept them?

EDIT :

Okay so I found the part answer. For the android.opengl.GLES10 all I need to do is use that object because the whole class consists of static functions, so no need to create or pass the object, there is need of none. I am still unsure on the EGLConfig part.

Comment: I had a similar problem building [Google's own sample code](https://developer.android.com/training/graphics/opengl/environment.html#renderer).  Android Studio imported `android.opengl.EGLConfig` rather than  `javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLConfig`, causing a similar error.  Manually making the substitution seems to fixed this.  Decompiled with Fernflower, android.opengl.GLSurfaceView itself includes a reference to  javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLConfig, so I feel confident adding the import to remove the compile exception.  I'm not sure why AS didn't correctly resolve this though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having similar classes with partly the same names in both `javax.microedition.khronos.egl` and in `android.opengl` is indeed confusing, and somewhat unfortunate. Partly based on the API level where these classes were added to the SDK, my guess is that they started out with the `javax` classes (`GL10` is marked with API level 1) because standard interfaces were available for what they needed at the time. Then later, they might have realized that they needed more, and started adding them as new classes (`android.opengl.GLES10` is API level 4). And they kept the old classes for backwards compatibility. All of this is just my interpretation, I don't have any inside knowledge.

You can't override `onSurfaceCreated()` while declaring the first argument as `android.opengl.GLES10`. While it might have pretty much the same member functions as `GL10`, they are completely separate classes, and Java will therefore consider them different types. So the signature will not match the base class method you need to override if you change the argument to `GLES10`.

As you already figured out based on your updates, this is a non-issue. All methods on these classes are static, so you don't need an instance. You can simply ignore the `GL10` argument, and make your OpenGL calls with the syntax for static methods, where the call is qualified with a class name instead of an instance:

```
GLES10.glClearColor(...);
```

Or if you're using ES 2.0 (strongly recommended, and supported by 99.9% of all actively used devices):

```
GLES20.glClearColor(...);
```

On the `EGLConfig`, that gets much more interesting. I found a solution which isn't particularly elegant, but it's the best I could come up with. The basic idea is to get the id of the config from the old interface, and then retrieve the config with that id using the new interface.

I'll separate the two parts so that I don't have to qualify all the class names. This part is in code that operates with the `javax.microedition.khronos.egl` classes:

```
EGLConfig config = ...;  // your given config
EGLDisplay display = EGL10.eglGetCurrentDisplay();
int valA[] = new int[1];
EGL10.eglGetConfigAttrib(display, config, EGL10.EGL_CONFIG_ID, valA);
int configId = valA[0];
```

Now `configId` is the id of your config. This code now operates with the `android.opengl` classes:

```
EGLDisplay display = EGL14.eglGetCurrentDisplay();
int[] attribA = {EGL14.EGL_CONFIG_ID, configId, EGL14.EGL_NONE};
EGLConfig[] configA = new EGLConfig[1];
int[] nConfigA[] = new int[1];
EGL14.eglChooseConfig(display, attribA, 0, configA, 0, 1, nConfigA, 0);
EGLConfig newConfig = configA[0];
```

`newConfig` is now your config of type `android.opengl.EGLConfig`.

Comment: "your given config" would be the EGLConfig object which we are getting in the parameters, right?

Comment: @flide: Yes, exactly.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this helped me with a related problem